# How can I remove a 302 redirect on a WordPress site?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a WordPress site that is on a windows(plesk) server. There is no web.config file and from all the reading and speaking to others it seems that a 302 redirect is coming from the web-config.php file. Does anyone know what specifically I am looking for to remove?

Specifically, the site is redirecting from http://www.davybrown.com to http://www.davybrown.com/ there is a bit of code that looks like this:

```
/** WordPress absolute path to the Wordpress directory. */
if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');
```

Am I stupid to assume that it's just a case of removing the . '/' and that will be that sorted?

Thanks

Comment: maybe this could be of help for you http://www.victor-ratajczyk.com/post/2012/02/07/Webconfig-httpRedirect-Redirecting-individual-pages-with-301-302-and-307-status-codes.aspx

Answer (score 0):

WordPress is redirecting it to the Canonical URL. If you don't want that, add this to your [functions.php](http://www.wpbeginner.com/glossary/functions-php/)

```
remove_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical' );
```